# Install different Java JDK versions on Mountain Lion

Tags: java, java-6

I'm running the latest version of Mountain Lion, and i would like to install a specific Java JDK version (1.6.0_21). I've searched around here and googled it but i can't seem to find:

- Where to download specific Mac versions of Java, besides the ones that Apple gives
- How to install a different one that the "automated" downloader of Mountain Lion gets

Is there any way to do it or i'm looking for the impossible?

The reason why i want it it's to keep aligned with the version installed at my local university.

Answer (score 0):

Just grab the installer from Oracle.